# 2nd gear ghost shifts to 1st gear

Tags: mountain-bike

Initially my bike had a problem with the rear derailleur being able to shift into the spokes.

The mechanic said the limit screws needed adjusting. But am still having ghost shifting into first when in the second gear. It doesn't appear to do it in others and only appears to happen consistently when am pedaling hard.

Does this mean the lower limit just needs a slight tweak?

Comment: Needs more adjustment

Comment: Does it shift smoothly to the biggest sprocket? I assume not? First I’d try increasing the cable tension. If that doesn’t improve things you should slowly unscrew the limit screw until shifting to the big sprocket works reliably.

Comment: Loosen the cable using the adjuster for the rear derailleur slightly. If you find that this causes the other gears to shift incorrectly, check for bent or worn teeth on the 2nd ring on your cassette, if any are out of line it could be driving the chain in to the 'guide' channels on the first ring.